# Replace truncated strings in some records with full strings from other records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replace

I am working with SQL Server 2014.

I have a data-set with company names that are sometimes truncated due to space limitations at source. `E.g. AAA PTY Ltd` would sometimes appear as `'AAA PTY L'` and sometimes as the original non truncated name depending on the source. I need to replace the truncated values with the long ones where it is truncated to avoid duplicate records when matching with other data-sets. Replacing the full names with the truncated ones is easy but I need it the other way round.

I created a table with the long names and the truncated ones, ordered it descending (so the long name always appear before the truncated ones) and add a column for the truncated names (mimic the truncation where the full name was not truncated). I also created a flag to indicate if it was truncated so I can easily identify the records I need to update. 
So the table I created looks like this:

```
|Id | FullName     | Truncated name | TruncFlag|
+---+--------------+----------------+----------+
|1  | AAA PTY Ltd  | AAA PTY L      | 1        |
|2  | AAA PTY L    | AAA PTY L      | 0        |
|3  | BBB PTY Ltd  | BBB PTY L      | 1        |
|4  | BBB PTY L    | BBB PTY L      | 0        |
```

I need to replace the full name in the second and fourth rows with the full name in the first and third rows respectively.

I tried to do that with `JOINS` (subqueries counting the number of full names per truncated name having count > 1) and also with while loops, storing the truncated and full names in variables, but it's beyond my capability.

I would like to get to a table like (after updating FullNames in second and fourth rows):

```
|Id | FullName     | Truncated name | TruncFlag|
+---+--------------+----------------+----------+
|1  | AAA PTY Ltd  | AAA PTY L      | 1        |
|2  | AAA PTY Ltd  | AAA PTY L      | 0        |
|3  | BBB PTY Ltd  | BBB PTY L      | 1        |
|4  | BBB PTY Ltd  | BBB PTY L      | 0        |
```

Comment: While there are solutions that achieve what you want, I think a bigger question is why you have different representations of the same company name (truncated vs. non-truncated) in the same table. Unless this is a staging table, there should be only one representation for each company. For example, have a `Companies` table, with a `company_id` auto-incrementing intege value, or some natural key (e.g. the company's stock symbol). That way, you're avoiding this sort of issue by using proper normalization techniques.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution:

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.FullName = t2.FullName
FROM table_name t1 INNER JOIN table_name t2 ON t2.FullName LIKE t1.FullName + '%' 
    AND LEN(t2.FullName) > LEN(t1.FullName)
```

This solution doesn't use the `TruncFlag` and `TruncatedName` column to get the `FullName`. You can get the `FullName` from the other records. The solution joins the records with same start at the `FullName` column. With `LEN(t2.FullName) > LEN(t1.FullName)` you exclude all records where the found `FullName` is smaller than or the same length as the current (maybe truncated) `FullName`.

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=75f88c85f3ee9f1e69247def441db151)

Comment: @Hogan Not necessarily

Comment: The self join on the same table solves the problem. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Run the first query and see if that works out for the results you're expecting. Second query would be your update.

```
select t.fullname, 'will change to', l.fullname 
set t.fullname = l.fullname
from yourtable l
join yourtable t on l.truncatedname = t.truncatedname
where l.truncflag = 1
and t.truncflag=0

update t
set t.fullname = l.fullname
from yourtable l
join yourtable t on l.truncatedname = t.truncatedname
where l.truncflag = 1
and t.truncflag=0
```

Comment: I would be wary if you had similar names truncated, like AAA PTY L11 and AAA PTY L22, you could get undesirable joins. If it works out though please accept my answer for those nerd points. /cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a self join, put the intermediate results in a CTE, and then run the update. This example works for your limited data. If there are fringe cases where the truncated value looks the same as another truncated value, but the full name is different between the two, that will cause problems.

```
;with CTE AS (
SELECT 
t1.ID, 
t1.fullname AS fullname_actual, 
t2.fullname AS fullname_truncated

FROM your_table t1
INNER JOIN your_table t2
    ON t1.truncatedname = t2.truncatedname
    AND t1.fullname <> t2.fullname
    AND t1.truncflag = 1
    AND t2.truncflag = 0

)
UPDATE your_table 
SET fullname = fullname_actual
FROM cte 
WHERE fullname_truncated = fullname
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `EXISTS` without relying on the truncate flag.

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS
(
    SELECT
        T.Id,
        T.FullName,
        NewFullName = T.FullName + 'td'
    FROM
        YourTable AS T
    WHERE
        T.FullName LIKE '%L' AND
        EXISTS (
            SELECT
                'at least one full name matches with Ltd'
            FROM
                YourTable AS F
            WHERE
                F.FullName = T.FullName + 'td')
)
UPDATE T SET
    FullName = NewFullName
FROM
    ToUpdate AS T
```

Comment: You are making the assumption that the expanded name ends with 'td' and the fullname ends with L which might be incorrect.

Comment: That's right, since the OP just used 2 different examples with the same ending I just assumed that he needs to replace only this. Not knowing exactly what to replace might generate an incorrect match. For example `AAA L` will match `AAA LLL Ltd` and `AAA Ltd`

Comment: My point is you don't have to make those assumptions since the data is there with the fullname column.

Comment: This is true - this assumption is not correct. I solved the problem using the code from TEEKAY above. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.FullName = t2.FullName
FROM Truncated_table t1
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT FullName
    FROM Truncated_table
    WHERE [Truncated name] = t1.[Truncated name]
        AND TruncFlag = 1
    ) AS t2
WHERE TruncFlag = 0
```